# Ruby Cipher If statements not working

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I was wondering if someone could correct the things I have done wrong in my code. I am attempting to make a 1 time pad with Ruby.

Every time I run the code, and provide input to be put into the cipher, it returns a nil or a doesn't return the exact amount of characters (I enter in a 4 character word and it returns 2 characters).

```
h = {}
v = 0

('A'..'Z').each do |c|
  v+=1
  h[c] = v
end 

puts "Provide Input:"
input = gets
input.downcase!


if input.include?("a") 
    n = h["A"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("b")
    n = h["B"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("c")
    n = h["C"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n)  
    end
if input.include?("d")
    n = h["D"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("e")
    n = h["E"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("f")
    n = h["F"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("g")
    n = h["G"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("h")
    n = h["H"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("i")
    n = h["I"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("j")
    n = h["J"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("k")
    n = h["K"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("l")
    n = h["L"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("m")
    n = h["M"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("n")
    n = h["N"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("o")
    n = h["O"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("p")
    n = h["P"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("q")
    n = h["Q"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("r")
    n = h["R"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("s")
    n = h["S"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("t")
    n = h["T"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("u")
    n = h["U"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("v")
    n = h["V"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("w")
    n = h["W"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n)
    end
if input.include?("x")
    n = h["X"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("y")
    n = h["Y"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("z")
    n = h["Z"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
```

What is wrong with my code? Is there a better way I can do this, and/or is there a way I can make it more effective and efficient.

Quick final question, is there a better place to run my code than in TextMate on a Mac running OS X 10.9.3?

Most Recent Version:

```
h = {}
v = 0

('A'..'Z').each do |c|
  v+=1
  h[c] = v
end 

puts "Provide Input:"
input = gets
input.downcase!
input.each_char {|n| puts n, ' ' }


if input.include?("a") 
    n = h["A"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("b")
    n = h["B"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("c")
    n = h["C"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26)  
    end
if input.include?("d")
    n = h["D"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("e")
    n = h["E"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("f")
    n = h["F"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("g")
    n = h["G"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("h")
    n = h["H"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("i")
    n = h["I"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("j")
    n = h["J"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("k")
    n = h["K"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n) 
    end
if input.include?("l")
    n = h["L"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("m")
    n = h["M"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("n")
    n = h["N"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("o")
    n = h["O"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("p")
    n = h["P"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("q")
    n = h["Q"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("r")
    n = h["R"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("s")
    n = h["S"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("t")
    n = h["T"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("u")
    n = h["U"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("v")
    n = h["V"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("w")
    n = h["W"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26)
    end
if input.include?("x")
    n = h["X"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("y")
    n = h["Y"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
if input.include?("z")
    n = h["Z"] + rand(26)
    puts h.index(n % 26) 
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your code, h["Z"] == 26.  If you then add a random number up to 26, (let's say 4), you have 30.  h.index(30) would be nil.  I would wager you want to h.index(n%26).

EDIT:

complete code, based partially on the other answer given:

```
h = {}
v = 0

('A'..'Z').each do |c|
    h[c] = v
    v+=1
end

puts "Provide Input:"
input = gets

input.chomp.each_char do |c|
    next if c.upcase !~ /^[A-Z]$/
    n = h[c.upcase] + rand(26)
    puts h.key(n % 26)
end
```

Comment: That works great, but it appears to be cutting one letter off of the input. So when I entered the word "Doctor", it only returns 5 scrambled letters instead of 6.

Comment: You're checking each letter of the alphabet once instead of each letter of your word.  You only check for "O" once, but there are two O's in your word.  Iterate over your string instead.  Also, you'll do better if you put v += 1 *after* h[c] = v, so that h is 0 indexed instead of 1 index.  With a 1 index, n % 26 will never yield you a Z

Comment: Alright I get that, but I am also very bad with Ruby. So I tried using "input.split("").each do |i|". But how do I iterate over a string, in this instance?

Comment: each_char is the method you want.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html might be helpful.

Comment: Although I did that, it still will ignore characters that exist in the same string (The l in hello). So I added a:         "input.each_char {|n| puts n, ' ' }"                                 after the input.downcase!

Comment: The other answer has a decent code sample for iterating over the string.  If it's still not working, post your latest code and we'll see where you're going wrong.

Comment: I see your problem somewhat now.  The 5 line 'each_char' loop in the answer provided by user3530367 is actually intended to replace the entire group of 26 if statements you have.

Comment: The 5 lines of user3530367's code does not change anything, because when I replace the ifs with it, it just reprints the string I entered, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I hadn't actually tried executing his.  Edited my answer just now to be a functional version.

Comment: when it asks for input, and I give it, it doesn't work.

Comment: took the above code, put it in a file called cypher.rb and ran it: ruby cypher.rb 
Provide Input:
Doctor
E
S
M
J
K
V

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bit more like ruby way to write this

```
h = {}
v = 0

('A'..'Z').each do |c|
  v+=1
  h[c] = v
end

puts "Provide Input:"
input = gets

input.chomp!.each_char do |c|
  next if (c.upcase! =~ /^[A-Z]$/) == 0
  n = h["#{c}"] + rand(26)
  puts h.index(n%26)
end
```